# Unable to boot Kali Linux from External Hard Drive, with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, external-hard-drive, kali-linux

I have installed Kali Linux on an external hard drive. ON my laptop Ubuntu is installed. When I connect the external hard drive via USB cable and booted the laptop from external USB/hard drive. Kali Linux welcome screen appears but after that instead of showing login screen of Kali Linux it shows login screen of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I ask is because the wifi adapter I use for injection takes up 2 USB ports on my Mac when it's plugged in. This means I won't be able to use it if the external USB has to stay plugged in because my Mac has 2 USB ports. So...does the external USB you boot kali from have to stay plugged in while using kali?